# A new Joomla service - Site building on www.joomla.com.

Tags: discussion

I was messing around today and I had the idea to try what I would get at [**www.joomla.com**](https://www.joomla.com).
Then I discovered this new service
I have never ever before heard of the Joomla.com.
Thought you would also like to know, so I shared the news here...

As for the JSE; we shall be prepared for questions related to this service?

Answer (score 6):

I was quite happy they got this up and running as it's a nice handy thing to have.

One thing we need to bare in mind when answering questions by user who are using the free `joomla.com` subdomain, is that that have no access over server setup or cannot install extensions. Therefore our ability to assist users will be fairly limited. If the question is regarding the actual usage of Joomla, then fair enough.

Also, when we see a question by a user who is using this free service, I would suggest checking the [Tutorials](http://tutorials.joomla.com/) section as their question may have already been answered.

Just incase, I have set up a free account on there:

https://stackexchange.joomla.com/

Thought it could be used at some point. If any of your have any ideas for it, post below of if you would like an admin account on there, feel free to email me (lodder15[at]hotmail.co.uk) and I'll reply with your login details

Answer (score 2):

It is useful to know if a question is being asked about joomla.com compared to the full version of Joomla as obviously there are some limitations with joomla.com.

Most joomla.com users are probably beginners unaware of the difference between joomla.com and the full version.

It may be useful to create a joomla.com tag to help identify and group these questions.